# websphere jre timezone incorrect

Tags: java, websphere

We have two linux application servers at my work both with websphere 6.1 installed. I've written a simple stand alone java application to print the current time.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
            System.out.println("the default timezone is " + tz.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.LONG));
            System.out.println("the default timezone ID is " + tz.getID());
            System.out.println("useDaylightTime = " + tz.useDaylightTime());
    }
```

On box application server **a** I get...

```
the default timezone is Eastern Summer Time (New South Wales)
the default timezone ID is Australia/Sydney
useDaylightTime = true
```

On box application server **b** I get...

```
the default timezone is GMT+10:00
the default timezone ID is GMT+10:00
useDaylightTime = false
```

I want application server **b** to be the same as **a**. Can someone assist me with what I might need to do to make this happen?

thanks

Comment: You may want to see [3 Ways to Change the Timezone in Linux - wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Timezone-in-Linux)

Comment: @Paul. Hi, I don't think this is a system time problem. When I type in date on the command line the times are identical. I think this is a java jre time issue.

Comment: Did you mean that the **timezones** in both machines are the same?

Comment: Your servers are set to different time settings.  EST and GMT+10 are an hour apart. If your command line says the same time, the settings are not the same.

Comment: @CharlieS I read your comment a few times but I'm struugling to understand it. On my command line of both box a and box b when I issue the following commands :date and also zdump :/etc/localtime the outputs on both boxes are the same. I am confused about what you means when you say if the command line says the same then they are not the same? thanks

Comment: What is the value of your TZ environment variable for machine b?  echo $TZ

Comment: it is not set on both machines

Comment: Did you run timedatectl on both machines?  Is it the same output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the getDefault() method, if not cached, Java will

```
Use the user.timezone property value as the default time zone ID if it's available.
Detect the platform time zone ID.
Use GMT as the last resort if the given or detected time zone ID is unknown.
```

Based on your reported output, it appears as though the application server b does not have the user.timezone property set.
According to  http://chandank.com/application-server/was/set-timezone-in-websphere-application-server, you can set the timezone following these steps

```
1. Start the administrative console.
2. In the topology tree, expand Servers >> Application Servers.
3. Click on application server for which you want to set the time zone
4. On the application server page, click Process Definition>>Java Virtual Machine>>Custom Properties>>New
5. Specify user.timezone in the Name field and timezone in the Value field, where timezone is the supported value for your time zone.
6. Click Apply/ok
7. Save the configuration


ex :  Name - user.timezone
     value - Asia/Singapore
```

So I would verify that it is set properly for your b system. In your case you would change Asia/Singapore to Australia/Sydney

If the procedure above doesn't work (for whatever reason), I just setting your timezone via the clock settings should fix it assuming that you can do that.  I do not have a Websphere system available to test it.

Comment: thanks for these comments. I've checked the websphere console for user.timezone on box b and it is not there as a custom property. I guess that means that it is usign the platform time zone id. But I think they are set to the same on both boxes (see my comment to @Charlie).

Comment: Were you able to try adding it as a New custom property per step 4 or was that option not available?  I believe the property not being there would explain the problem since it than would default to GMT time.

Comment: it wasn't set on both machines so originally i did not try and set it but i just attempted setting it on box a and guess what ... it worked! thanks. Still some difference between my two boxes though. But that's okay. Appreciate your help